# Navigation bar change my items positions after show AlertViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I got 2 icons on my navigation bar, but when I show an `alertViewController`those icons change their positions.

Those are my icons.

[image]

And this happens when I show the `alertViewController`

[image]

This is my `viewController` content.

```
UIBarButtonItem *helpItem;
UIBarButtonItem *helpItem1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self setup];
}

-(void)setup{
        helpItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(helpButtonItemTapped:)];

        helpItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(helpButtonItemTapped:)];

        helpItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];

        helpItem1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  helpItem, helpItem1, nil];
}

-(void)helpButtonItemTapped:(id)sender{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                          message:nil
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet
                                          ];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
                                ]];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your init UIBarbuttonItem code to this

```
 helpItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"memoAccess"] style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(helpButtonItemTapped:)];
helpItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"memoAccess"] style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(helpButtonItemTapped:)];
```

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but in Swift 3 , this is how I managed to fix it. I changed the following code :

```
    let BarButtonItemVariable : UIBarButtonItem!
    BarButtonItemVariable = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.SomeMethod))
    BarButtonItemVariable.image = UIImage(named: "SomeImage")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = BarButtonItemVariable
```

To this:

```
    let BarButtonItemVariable : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named : "SomeImage"), target: self, style: .plain, action: #selector(self.SomeMethod))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = BarButtonItemVariable
```